# What are assertions in JEST?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

It's documentation says that while dealing with async code, `expect.assertions(x)` should be written.
What exactly do assertions refer to? Is it a term of plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this context, it's testing terminology, it doesn't have a special meaning.

With `expect.assertions(n)`, you're telling Jest that you expect the current test to perform `n` assertions. An assertion is a check that values meet certain conditions.

In other words, if you use `expect.assertions(5)` the test will fail unless `expect()` is called at least 5 times.

This is useful for async tests, but it's not the only way to handle asynchronicity, you can find other patterns in the [Jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous).